How do I teleport camera without teleporting the navmesh with it in aframe?
I want to know how I teleport the camera without teleporting the nav-mesh
I'm making a maze game with clickable portals where it teleports my camera to another portal, BUT it also teleports the nav-mesh with it, causing the walls to be all funky!
I thought my code would just teleport the camera to the location, but it teleported the nav mesh along with it:
<!--Nav-Mesh-->
<a-gltf-model src="Models/navmeshNew.gltf" position="0 0 0" nav-mesh visible="false"></a-gltf-model>
<a-entity id="rig" position="0 0 0" movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true; speed: 0.5;">
  <a-entity camera id="camera" position="0 3.5 0" look-controls extended-wasd-controls>
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>

<!--Portals-->
<a-box color="white" id="p1" position="0 4 -8" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5" animation="
        property: rotation;
        to: 360 360 360;
        dur: 5000;
        loop: true;
        easing: linear;" onClick="goToP1()" src="Images/portalImage.jpeg"></a-box>

<a-box color="red" id="p2" position="-2 7 -22" scale="4 12 4" onClick="goToP2()"></a-box>

/**Functions**/

function goToP1() {
  camera.setAttribute("position", "-6 3.5 -22")
}

